# Need help building a Data Item in Cognos Report Studio

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi, cognos-8, cognos-tm1

So I have a table with employee name, job and shift.  Each employee (Row) has a unique name, a non unique job and one of 4 shifts (A, B, ,C or D).  I want to create a Data Item called "Shift A Employees" that that for each job it spits out one string that contains all the employees who work that ob on that shift for example:

[I have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3nw2.png)

[And want to be able to have this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y88GZ.png)

How would I go about writing my expression definition for my "Shift A Employees" data item?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please share the [relevant parts of the code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) you have developed so far. This helps figuring out what the problem could be. Also please edit your question to have necessary pictures be displayed inline. For help see ["How to Ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a data item that does that could be rather involved.  Why not drag a repeater table onto your list?  You will need to add two data items to the query.  One is `running-count(1 for [Job])` (I think.  I don't have my example in front of me right now.)  The other compares that value to the maximum value for the job.  If the values match it returns nothing, if it doesn't it returns a comma.  Here's the pattern:

```
case
when [rownum] < [maxrownum] then ','
else ''
end
```

Name it `comma`.
Then you just drag [Name] and [comma] to the repeater table.  Make the repeater table 1 row high and more columns wide than you think you'll need.
You'll need to define a master-detail relationship for the repeater table.